# Enlightenment Desktop Connection Manager Blank

Tags: enlightenment, connman

I switched desktop managers to Enlightenment. I love it. But the connection manager gadget shows nothing. It is just an empty box with 'wifi on' at the bottom. I made sure connman-gtk was installed. It still shows nothing.

I am running Enlightenmnet. Here is my neofetch just for some basic info about my system.

OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64
Host: GWTC116-2
Kernel: 6.2.0-31-generic
Uptime: 2 hours, 16 mins
Packages: 2518 (dpkg), 16 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.2.15
Resolution: 1366x768
WM: Enlightenment
Theme: Numix [GTK2/3]
Icons: oxygen [GTK2/3]
Terminal: qterminal
Terminal Font: Monospace 11
CPU: Intel Celeron N4020 (2) @ 2.800GHz
GPU: Intel GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 600]
Memory: 1810MiB / 3728MiB

Yes, I know. It is a modest machine to say the least. But it runs Enlightenment beautifully. Except the network manager gadget. That thing is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did some research.

sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service

Executing the above command and rebooting fixed the problem and now the gadget shows networks detected and which one is connected. Nice!

On the downside, I have found that a lot of the themes you can install for Enlightenment have a speaker icon for the network gadget for some reason. It is still the right info if you click on it, but it looks like the same icon for sound settings. The nerdy matrix theme is the exception, with an oversized network icon that we all recognize. I guess I could manually change the gadget icon myself somehow if I want to use another theme that has the wrong one.

Also, I have found that the print screen function doesn't work in Enlightenment using my Fn and F11 combo as it does in the regular Ubuntu environment. I will try to work out a keybinding for that function if I can figure out what app is used in Enlightenment to take screenshots.